# Word or phrase for "incorrectly or underutilized tool or concept"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am looking for a word or phrase to describe a situation where a tool or concept is being used incorrectly or underutilized.

One example would be using a screwdriver as a hammer.

Another example would be teaching a lesson but it has no value.

Comment: You'll have to give an example situation or sentence.

Comment: One example would be using a screwdriver as a hammer.
Another example would be teaching a lesson but it has no value.

Comment: Indeed - as it stands, what's wrong with, say, *used incorrectly* or *underutilised*?

Answer (score 1):

Simple options include [misuse](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/misuse) and [misapply](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/misapply) defined by Merriam Webster as follows.

**Misuse** and its synonym **misapply** meaning

> To use incorrectly

Also try **misemploy**.